# Create a column with values of a list and depending on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, data-manipulation

- I have a list of paths of different images:

`img_dir = [img_pathA.1.jpg, img_pathA.2.jpg, img_pathA.3.jpg, img_pathB.1.jpg, img_pathB.2.jpg, .... img_pathZ.3.jpg]`

- And a dataframe with an `ID` column:

`df`:

| ID |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| .. |
| Z |

As you can see, every image path in the list contains in its filename the ID who belongs to.

I would like to add all the image paths for every ID in the dataframe. The goal is to get something like this:

`final_df`:

| ID | img_path |
| --- | --- |
| A | img_pathA.1.jpg |
| A | img_pathA.2.jpg |
| A | img_pathA.3.jpg |
| B | img_pathB.1.jpg |
| B | img_pathB.2.jpg |
| .. | ............ |
| Z | img_pathZ.3.jpg |

The numbers of images per ID is not fixed (usually 2-3 images per ID), so I have thought that I could replicate the entire dataframe maybe 3 times, do the assignment for every row and after that, delete the rows that doesn't have a path ("No path").

I have tried the following code:

```
df['img_path'] = "No path"
df = pd.concat([df]*3, ignore_index=True)

for ID in df['ID']:
    for path in img_dir:
        if ID in path:
            df.loc[(df['ID'] == ID), 'img_path'] = path
```

But I get something like this. I think that it's because the ID gets replicated too and the column  seems to store the last image for every ID:

| ID | img_path |
| --- | --- |
| A | img_pathA.3.jpg |
| A | img_pathA.3.jpg |
| A | img_pathA.3.jpg |
| B | img_pathB.2.jpg |
| B | img_pathB.2.jpg |
| .. | ............ |
| Z | img_pathZ.3.jpg |

Any idea of how could I solve or improve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a series from the `img_dir` list then `extract` the `ID` from the corresponding paths and set the extracted `ID` as the index of the series, then `join` the dataframe with this series on the column `ID`

```
s = pd.Series(img_dir)
s.index = s.str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(df['ID'])})", expand=False)

df.join(s.rename('img_path'), on='ID')
```

---

```
  ID          img_path
0  A   img_pathA.1.jpg
0  A   img_pathA.2.jpg
0  A   img_pathA.3.jpg
1  B   img_pathB.1.jpg
1  B   img_pathB.2.jpg
...
3  Z   img_pathZ.3.jpg
```